# Why does one of four-way handshake miss with the command nc

Tags: tcp, tcpdump, time-wait, nc

I'm using the command `nc` to simulate the TCP connection with a client and a server.

I execute the command `nc -l 1234` and `tcpdump -i eth0 port 1234` at the server and I execute the command `nc IP_OF_SERVER 1234` at the client.

Then I type `abcd` and a `Ctrl+D` at the client.

On the terminal of `tcpdump`, I get the output as below:

```
13:35:11.800516 IP 172.19.48.20.51678 > 172.19.48.2.1234: Flags [S], seq 3620507131, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2065731649 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
13:35:11.800529 IP 172.19.48.2.1234 > 172.19.48.20.51678: Flags [S.], seq 451776773, ack 3620507132, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1583409528 ecr 2065731649,nop,wscale 7], length 0
13:35:11.800586 IP 172.19.48.20.51678 > 172.19.48.2.1234: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 2065731649 ecr 1583409528], length 0
13:35:13.793724 IP 172.19.48.20.51678 > 172.19.48.2.1234: Flags [P.], seq 1:6, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 2065733642 ecr 1583409528], length 5
13:35:13.793733 IP 172.19.48.2.1234 > 172.19.48.20.51678: Flags [.], ack 6, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 1583410026 ecr 2065733642], length 0
13:35:18.442459 IP 172.19.48.20.51678 > 172.19.48.2.1234: Flags [F.], seq 6, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 2065738291 ecr 1583410026], length 0
13:35:18.442479 IP 172.19.48.2.1234 > 172.19.48.20.51678: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 7, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 1583411188 ecr 2065738291], length 0
13:35:18.442520 IP 172.19.48.20.51678 > 172.19.48.2.1234: Flags [.], ack 2, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 2065738291 ecr 1583411188], length 0
```

So, I can see that there are three-way handshake at the beginning, a sending-message with the length 5 to the server and an ack to the client, these are exactly what I expected.

However, it seems that there are only three records about disconnection. As we all know, TCP needs the four-way handshake to disconnect. Why are there only three records, instead of four?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As we all know, TCP needs the four-way handshake to disconnect.

TCP does not need a four-**way** handshake to disconnect. It instead needs a four-**step** handshake:

1. A sends a FIN
2. B sends an ACK to the FIN
3. B sends a FIN
4. A sends an ACK to B's FIN

The steps 2+3 can be merged into a single step where a packet with FIN+ACK is send, and this is here the case:

```
[1]    13:35:18.442459 A > B: Flags [F.], seq 6, ack 1, ...
[2+3]  13:35:18.442479 B > A: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 7, ... 
[4]    13:35:18.442520 A > B: Flags [.], ack 2, ...
```